# Can I say "session data is available on the client temporarily for surfing period but stored permanently on server"?

Tags: session-management

While I was searching for the differences between cookie and session, I came across two of the following statements

1. session data is stored on the server, while cookie data is stored on the client.
2. session data available for the browser run, after closing the browser we will lose the session information.
   [Source Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478805/what-is-difference-between-session-and-cookie-in-php)

They appeared a little-bit contradictory to me.
Can I say "session data is available on the client temporarily for surfing period but stored permanently on server"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you may not.   Well, you might, of course, if you were so inclined, but that would be incorrect.   Session data, server-side or otherwise, is not ever supposed to be permanent.  I think it may be the absurd overloading of the term "session" which is causing you confusion.

To wit:

1. A **session cookie** is something stored on the client side, and does not have an expiration date but expires (and is deleted) when the browser session ends. (The browser is closed, in other words.)
2. A **persistent cookie**  has an embedded expiration date which may (amusingly enough) cause it to expire before the browser session ends, or more generally be persisted across multiple browser sessions by saving it to disk for re-use.
3. **Session state** (or server-side sessions, or session variables) is data that is persisted for a short time (usually a sliding 20 to 30 minutes, by default) that is associated with a client (browser) session, and referenced by a session id that is both the key for the server side session data object and the value for a session cookie that the client sends with each request.   If the browser does not make a request within the timeout period (again, usually 20 to 30 minutes by default) or even potentially before that, if the application requests that the session for that client end, then that data will be deleted from the server.

Session state data is often stored in memory on the web server, and thus will not be permanently persisted, and in many cases will not even survive a restart of the web server process, even if the sessions are technically still valid and alive.

This can be mitigated by using a dedicated session state process, or storing session state in a database, but in no case is it ever intended to be a permanent data store.